# Django: set language

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm totally new in Django

I want to make a language field in Admin panel, the admin can set the language of the user, it can be 1 or many languages. For example, person 1 can speak english, French and japanese and another only in french. How can we do that?

[image]

My User model looks like that

Model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.get_full_name()}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you construct a `Language` model, for example:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    code2 = models.CharField(max_length=2, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

we can populate that, for example with `('en', 'English')` and `('fr', 'French')` and `('ja', 'Japanese')`.

Next we add a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) between the `Profile` and the `Language`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, related_name='speakers')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.get_full_name()}'
```

In the admin, we can make selecting languages more convenient with:

```
from django.contrib import admin


class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    autocomplete_fields = ('languages',)
```